# Rails: Return all objects when no matching result found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a simple search form in Rails.

```
  def self.search(query)
    where("sequence like ? or content LIKE ? ", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  end
```

The problem is that, when no result found, it will return an empty array.

How can I handle the `no result found` situation? How can I display a `notice` or return `.all` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would leave the `search` method as is. It's meaning is clear: look for data given a query.

Then in your controller or view I would handle the case where no results are found.

Generally, if I look for something, and there are no results, I would rather be notified then be shown all results (without any mention), that would confuse me.

So you could handle that in the controller, something like:

```
@posts = Post.search(params[:search]
if @posts.empty?
  flash[:notice] = "No results found for #{params[:search]}"
  @posts = Post.all 
end
```

But even easier, you handle this in the view, as follows:

```
<% if @posts.empty? %>
  <p>No results found</p>
<% else %>
  <table>
    .. render your table with results as before ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution would be to just check the results

```
def self.search(query)
  result = where("sequence like ? or content LIKE ? ", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  if result.blank?
    return all
  else
    return result
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this:

```
  def self.search(query)
    result = where("sequence like ? or content LIKE ? ", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
    result.any? ? result : all
  end
```

Note that this is TJ's answer with a slight modification for the sake of brevity.